# How to separate registration container using Ruby dry-rb?

Tags: ruby, dry-rb

Are there ways to separate the registration container into multiple features as modules when exploring the dry-rb gems, particularly the auto-injector, as a newcomer to Ruby?

Here is a code sample I tried but did not work.

```rb
module SomeFeatureContainter
    extend Dry::Container::Mixin

    register "some_service" do
        SomeService.new
    end
    
end


class Container
    extend Dry::Container::Mixin
    include SomeFeatureContainter

    
end

IocResolve = Dry::AutoInject(Container)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve the inversion of control, you can define a container and set the injector before invoke the service though your instantiated object.

`````
require 'dry-auto_inject'


class SomeService
  # your service definition
end

module SomeFeatureContainer
  extend Dry::Container::Mixin

  register 'some_service' do
    SomeService.new
  end
end

class Container
  extend Dry::Container::Mixin
  configure { |config| config.auto_inject = true }
  include SomeFeatureContainer

  # define the injector
  IocResolve = Dry::AutoInject(self)
end

class MyClass
  include Container::IocResolve[:some_service]

  def use_some_service
    some_service.call
  end
end

# invoke the service with MyClass
my_instance = MyClass.new
my_instance.use_some_service````
`````